# Send Custom Font to SMS Manager

Tags: android, fonts, sms, font-face, smsmanager

I have to send the message with the typeface set to a text in our SMSManager.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null,
                                null);
```

The sms comes from the edittext having .ttf typeface set.The sms is sent to the particular phoneNo but the fontface is normal not the one which is set in the Edittext. Please anybody has any idea or code how to send the message with the fontface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help others who stuck with the same issue this is done by setting the unicode's in the edittext and send the unicoded string to the smsmanager as follows:

```
 string text = "\u24D7\u24D4\u24D8\u24D8\u24DB World"; 
    editText.setText(text );
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                     intent.setType("text/plain");
                     intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT",  text );
                     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```